# How to link third party libraries properly in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I'm new in iOS development, and met this library linking problem in last few days.

I was trying to use [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) in a project, but cannot make it working.

This project is shipped as static library, so I just drag the xcodeproj file in my project. Then I added libGMGridView.a in *Link Binary With Libraries,* GMGridView in *Target Dependencies*. I also added the path in *Header Search　Paths*.

However, Xcode still report .h file not found error when I tried to import GMGridView.h.

Could anyone give me a hand on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question should have some information for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250302/how-do-third-party-libraries-work-in-objective-c-and-xcode

Comment: What does your import statement look like?

Comment: Should look like this: import "GMGridView/GMGridView.h"

Comment: Weird. The error did disappear at first. But they jumped back when I built the app.

Comment: What are you using as a Header Search path?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Had the same issue!!! Made it work!!!! 
soooooooo:

1. copy GMGridView folder from https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView to your project dir
2. in xcode right click on any file group and choose add files
3. find GMGridView folder in your folder dir and choose GMGridView.xcodeproj - (dont copy, create groups not folders, add targets)
4. go to your project targets - search - HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS add-  GMGridView/**
5. select Building phases in settings - choose target dependencies and add GMGridView
6. select Building phases in settings - link binary libraries and add libGMGridView.a

import should be:

```
#import "GMGridView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Very odd - but very timely - that you were trying to figure this out at the precise time that I was as well.  Thanks for this, it works!

Comment: Im doing exactly as described but it still wont recognize ! please help!

Comment: provide some more information or contact me comonitos@gmail.com

Comment: @PedroLopez says: Make sure that you add the QuartzCore.framework library to your target as well

Comment: @user1980105 you don't know how to add search paths? Or what?

Comment: Do you add GMGridView/** in GMGridView.xcodeproj or in your actual project...or both?

Comment: For me, I didn't have GWGridView just one folder up from my project file.  I had to use ../../GMGridView/** for it to work.

Comment: This solution works perfectly, I would only add one thing.
You should add these linker flags to avoid the app to crash on tap: -ObjC -all_load